# How can I remove the new Facebook authentication dialog for applications?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I would like to know how to remove the new authentication dialog.

I mean, I want my application to be like this:

[image]

Not like this:

[image]

I tried in the advanced setting, but there isn't any option to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to decide which layout the dialog receives, as Facebook retains the option to adjust this in order to maximize conversion/user sentiment.

I guess the question is, *why* do you want the other layout? Why do you feel that this will be better suited? Do you have data pointing to this converting better than the other one?

Comment: The Problem is that with the old dialog all the permissions were listed in a list (as you can see from the first image), but now with the new one if I require the wall post permission another dialog will appear to ask the user to allow or skip the posting permission.

Comment: @user1440266 That's how it is - you should therefor ask for as few perms as possible, and then only ask for more when you actually need them.